# Issue with adding DatePickerDialog to project

Tags: java, android-studio

I follow this [example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) about adding `DatePicker` to my app when using Android Studio.

```
import      android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

     public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                                implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I can not even compile the project. Here is the error:

```
Error:(6, 42) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class DialogFragment
Error:(7, 36) java: package DatePickerDialog does not exist
```

I tried `import     android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;`, but it does not exist. Also I set my project to *API 11* as that is minimum api level for this control. Any ideas?

I got datePicker somehow working but now I have error when opening activity that contains datepicker:

```
07-16 18:17:36.274    1822-1822/mycalories.com.jalle.mycalories D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-16 18:17:36.274    1822-1822/mycalories.com.jalle.mycalories W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4db2b20)
07-16 18:17:36.274    1822-1822/mycalories.com.jalle.mycalories E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: mycalories.com.jalle.mycalories, PID: 1822
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{mycalories.com.jalle.mycalories/mycalories.com.jalle.mycalories.MealsEditActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1884)
            at mycalories.com.jalle.mycalories.MealsEditActivity.<init>(MealsEditActivity.java:23)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here is the activity

```
package mycalories.com.jalle.mycalories;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    import com.parse.Parse;
    import com.parse.ParseUser;

    //import android.app.DialogFragment;

    public class MealsEditActivity extends FragmentActivity implements mycalories.com.jalle.mycalories.DatePickerFragment.TheListener{
      public final EditText txtDate=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.meals_edit);

            Button btnDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDate);
            btnDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                           public void onClick(View v) {
                   Utils.MyToast("btnDate", getApplicationContext());

                   DialogFragment newFragment = new com.jalle.mycalories.DatePickerFragment();
                   newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
               }
           }
            );

        }

        public void returnDate(String date) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            txtDate.setText(date);
        }

        }
    }
```

What is wrong with this activity ?

Comment: I wonder why my question was edited ? I wrote http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html and that is the way I want URL to show, not like "example". The URL is more descriptive and as someone already knows what it is about he will not have to open the link. Is there any freedom of speech on the SO?

Comment: Stack Overflow questions and answers are a community-maintained wiki. Edits have to go through an approval process if made by users with less than 3,000 reputation, but in practice, very few edits are refused.

Answer (score 0):

have you add android support library to **build.gradle** of your application ?

for example :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}
```

then try to rebuild it.

**For exception :**
put

```
public final EditText txtDate=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
```

this line below

```
setContentView(R.layout.meals_edit);
```

Comment: I am not sure if my ap is build with gradle. How do I check that ?

Comment: In android studio ... with in your project there will be a build.gradle file... here is a example   http://xda-university.com/as-a-developer/getting-started-android-studio

Comment: It would be easier to go to the Project Structure dialog, choose your module from the list, go to the Dependencies tab, click the + button, choose "Library", and add a dependency on the v4 support library from the list that appears. Then you don't have to go mucking around in Gradle files, and there's no possibility that you will make edits in the wrong one (there's more than one build.gradle file in your project).

Comment: I have created new android studio project and moved al my clasess and resources to new project. Now projesct uses gradle system I think. ONly one problem left MealsEditActivity  crashes on opening (posted above) any ideas why ?